# I cannot remove some elements from my list in python even the number is greater than 5

Tags: python, python-3.x, anaconda

I have this list : `l = [2, 8, 1, 9, 11, 12, 3]`. I want to remove elements that is greater than 5 in my list.

My code look like this:

```
l = [2, 8, 1, 9, 11, 12, 3]
for x in l:
    if x > 5:
        l.remove(x)
print(l)
```

But I am getting output as : `[2, 1, 11, 3]`
I am using anaconda IDE. Please refer to image for more detail.

Comment: You should not be altering the list length while iterating over it. Instead you should build a new list with the items you want to keep

Comment: you are removing elements from the list you are iterating over! that is rarely a good idea! have a look at [list comprehensions](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html?highlight=comprehension#list-comprehensions).

Comment: A side note, Anaconda is not an IDE. It is a distribution of Python. Spyder is the IDE that comes with Anaconda.

Comment: The funny thing is that this question is a duplicate of a question that is a duplicate of a question that is a duplicate of a question XD

Comment: @SembeiNorimaki yep, this particular dupe is pretty circular. I just go for one that I think is a decent starting point in the loop. IIRC I did find the bottom of the spiral and it wasn't particularly great, better to start somewhere higher up and the OP can work their way through

Comment: @SembeiNorimaki added the original of the duplicates. i think the answers there are more helpful here...

Comment: Thank you for the answers. But what if the problem is to solve without creating any extra list?? And whats wrong with logic in above code? Can you please explain. I could not get it.

Comment: The linked answers already explain it in far more detail than we can do again. There's also another dupe: https://stackoverflow.com/a/6260097/4799172 that illustrates the issue, which you could get to from the initial dupe I linked

Answer (score 1):

As said in the comments, it's not the safest way to do it. Try this instead:

```
l = [2, 8, 1, 9, 11, 12, 3]
m =[]
for x in l:
    if x <= 5:
        m.append(x)
print(m)
```

Output:

```
[2, 1, 3]
```

Comment: `m = [n for n in l if n <= 5]` seems way more pythonic...

Comment: you're right, somehow I thought of correcting OP's code only